# Problem while Launching MoveIt! library loading error

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I'm using ROS Kinetic. For some reason there is a problem loading a library from OpenCV, as shown below:

```
[ERROR] [1544178952.950336396]: PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 'moveit_rviz_plugin/MotionPlanning' failed to load.  Error: Failed to load library /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libmoveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc3.so.3.3: undefined symbol: icv_y8_owns_rFFT_1_scale_32f)
```

I already tried to reinstall the Moveit! Package, opencv3 for ROS and rebuilding my local workspace but nothing seems to work, still getting the same results.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310215/problem-while-launching-moveit!-library-loading-error/) by [hpoleselo](https://answers.ros.org/users/37369/hpoleselo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2018-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Managed to fix it by trial and error. I suppose some OpenCV3 .so files from ROS were somehow conflicting with the OpenCV3.4.3 which i installed from source. Eventually what i ended up doing was just uninstall (going to /build folder and $ sudo make uninstall) my sourced/built OpenCV 3.4.3.

---

Originally posted by [hpoleselo](https://answers.ros.org/users/37369/hpoleselo/) with karma: 133 on 2018-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0